# How to check if a value is a property of an array in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am making a filter in angular.js. I'm trying to filter all the items if they contain the users id. How can I check if the users id is in the items array?

The id of the user is a property of this array : $scope.items.user.id

```
$scope.yourItemFilter = function(item) {

    //$scope.items is an array ($scope.items.user.id = undefined)
    if ($.inArray(item.user.id, $scope.items.user.id)) {
        return item;
    }

    return;
}
```

I could do a foreach on $scope.items and then put every $scope.item.user.id in an array. But this doesn't seem like a good way to do this

Comment: Is `$scope.items.user.id` array ?

Comment: no this should be an array of all the $scope.items.user.id, so first i thought of putting all these with a foreach in an array before doing this function. But i am looking for a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
if ($.inArray(item.user, $scope.items.user) && (item.user.id == $scope.items.user[$.inArray(item.user, $scope.items.user)].id))
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.inArray` returns the index of the element in the array, consider this:

```
$.inArray('a', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // 0
$.inArray('c', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // 2
$.inArray('d', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // -1
```

So you will need to the output:

```
if ($.inArray('a', ['a', 'b', 'c']) > -1) {
  // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and return as soon as you have a match:

```
$scope.yourItemFilter = function(item) {
    for (var scope_item of $scope.items) {
        if (scope_item.user.id === item.user.id) return item;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need the final `return` as functions return `undefined` by default.

An alternative way using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
$scope.yourItemFilter = function(item) {
    if ($scope.items.some(function (scope_item) {            
        return (scope_item.user.id === item.user.id) 
    })) return item;
}
```

Or if you have ES6 arrow support:

```
$scope.yourItemFilter = function(item) {
    if ($scope.items.some(scope_item => scope_item.user.id === item.user.id)) return item;
}
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back whether this, or any other answer, answered your question?